# How to open local file with InAppBrowser with recent changes to URL scheme in File plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm getting raw HTMl as JSON property from the server, then I create a new file on device filesystem using File plugin.

File plugin was returning absolute path to file, but after recent changes, File plugin now returns file location as URL scheme.

```
cdvfile://localhost/<filesystemType>/<path to file>
```

Is there a way to get an absolute path to file so it can be opened with InAppBrowser, or is there some other way to open files created by File plugin with InAppBrowser?

Comment: Any progress made towards this?  I have run into the exact same situation, and have been unable to find the correct path to the downloaded file.  Have tried `fileSystem.toURL() + filename`, `entry.toURL()`, `fileSystem.fullPath + filename`, and `entry.fullPath` to no avail.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `FileEntry.toURL()` - it could be opened within the InAppBrowser